# How to add redirect section to node edit on Drupal 8?

Tags: 8, redirection

On Drupal7 using [Redirect module](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) there was a section on node/nodeid/edit view where we could add a "Redirect" section. This was helpful because it allowed redirects to be created from the node/nodeid/edit view.

In Drupal8 that option is not available. How do you replicate the redirect section on the node/nodeid/edit view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a Drupal 7 feature but one from the redirect module. It partially exists in Drupal 8 as well but only lists the existing redirects, there is an issue open to add the ability to create a new redirect

Comment: you are correct, totally forgot to mention the redirect module. Let me update the question. Do you have a link to the open issue? i couldn't find it

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect/issues/2934356